# Evaluating escape sequences in perl

Tags: perl

I'm reading strings from a file. Those strings contain escape sequences which I would like to have evaluated before processing them further. So I do:

```
$t = eval("\"$t\"");
```

which works fine. But I'm having doubt about the performance. If eval is forking a perl process each time, it will be a performance killer. Another way I considered to do the job were regex, where I have found related questions in SO.

My question: is there a better, more efficient way to do it?

EDIT: before calling eval in my example $t is containing `\064\065\x20a\n`. It is evaluated to `45 a<LF>`.

Comment: That would be a performance killer. Luckily, `eval` does not fork a perl process each time it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite clear what the strings in the file look like and what you do to them before passing off to `eval`. There's something missing in the explanation.

If you simply want to undo C-style escaping (as also used in Perl), use [`Encode::Escape`](http://p3rl.org/Encode%3a%3aEscape):

```
use Encode qw(decode);
use Encode::Escape qw();
my $string_with_unescaped_literals = decode 'ascii-escape', $string_with_escaped_literals;
```

If you have placeholders in the file which look like Perl variables that you want to fill with values, then you are abusing `eval` as a poor man's templating engine. Use a [real one](https://socialtext.net/perl5/templates) that does not have the dangerous side effect of running arbitrary code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string =~ s/\\([rnt'"\\])/"qq|\\$1|"/gee
```

string eval can solve the problem too, but it brings up a host of security and maintenance issues, like @ in string

Answer (score 0):

oh gah don't use eval for this, thats dangerous if someone provides it with input like "system('sync;reboot');"..

But, you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$string = 'foo\"ba\\\'r';
printf("%s\n", $string);
$string =~ s/\\([\"\'])/$1/g;
printf("%s\n", $string);
```

Comment: I acknowledge that using eval can be dangerous, but in my case, with your example I could not have it working wrongly. Do you have an example which will trigger the problem?