# How to Make Perl Properly Interpret Unicode Bytes?

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

I have a really crappy file full of unicode bytes that I'm trying to clean up. Some examples from the file are as follows:

```
ブラック
roler coaster
digital social party
big bellie
cornacopia
\xd0\xb7\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f \xd1\x89\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0
```

Now, what I'd like to do is convert all those ugly byte points into real unicode text. So, the above would be output as:

```
ブラック
roler coaster
digital social party
big bellie
cornacopia
зубная щетка
```

I've been banging my head against how to do this in Perl for like an hour now, and I'm out of good ideas. If you have one, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: What do you mean by "unicode bytes"?  Does the line following "cornacopia" (it's spelled "cornucopia", BTW) actually contain backslash characters?  What kind of "real unicode text" do you want to produce (UTF-8? UTF-16? Something else?)

Comment: Yes it has the backslashes. I gave pasted exactly what's in the file. That's also why "cornacopia" is misspelled. I just want to convert it to utf8.

Comment: [Encode::Escape](http://p3rl.org/Encode::Escape), [String::Escape](http://p3rl.org/String::Escape) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740106/evaluating-escape-sequences-in-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660123/how-can-i-manually-interpolate-string-escapes-in-a-perl-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's UTF-8

```
$ perl -E'
    use open ":std", ":locale";
    use Encode qw( decode );
    $_ = q{\xd0\xb7\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f }.
         q{\xd1\x89\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0};
    s/\\x(..)/chr hex $1/seg;
    $_ = decode("UTF-8", $_);
    say;
'
зубная щетка
```